# Pybind11 TypeError. Python does not recognize known type

Tags: python, c++, cmake, typeerror, pybind11

I'm totally out of ideas. In short:

```
>>> franka_o80.function_using_mode(o80.Mode.QUEUE)
TypeError: dummy3(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: o80::Mode) -> None
Invoked with: Mode.QUEUE
```

In details:

1. There is a software `o80`, it has C++ `enum Mode`, and it is compiled into `o80.so`. There are also pybind11 bindings, exporting `enum Mode` into `o80.Mode` in `o80_python.so`.
2. There is a toy example `o80_example` with correspondent `o80_example.so` and `o80_example_python.so`. I can do:

```
import o80
import o80_example
o80_example.function_accepting_mode(o80.Mode.QUEUE)
```

3. There is my project, where I am doing same stuff, but I get what I pasted above. It seems like pybind finds no relations between `Mode` in `o80_python.so` and `o80::Mode` in code. I can even do `pybind11::class_<o80::Mode>("OtherMode");`, and then pass `OtherMode` in my `function_using_mode` - pybind sees no troubles. Functions from `o80` are generally working, the problem is only in types.

Also as a symptom:
This is normal: `(arg0: o80.Mode) -> None`
This is what I have: `(arg0: o80::Mode) -> None`

What I tried:

1. Playing with `typedef` and `unsing namespace`
2. Checking that `typeid().hash_code` and `typeid().name` are the same in `o80` and `franka_o80` - they are the same
3. Putting files in same directories as original - no help
4. Looking at compile instructions:

```
o80_example:
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC  -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic  -shared -Wl,-soname,libo80_example.so -o libo80_example.so CMakeFiles/o80_example.dir/src/driver_in.cpp.o CMakeFiles/o80_example.dir/src/driver_out.cpp.o CMakeFiles/o80_example.dir/src/standalone.cpp.o CMakeFiles/o80_example.dir/src/driver.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.71.0 /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libo80.so /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libsynchronizer.so /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libtime_series.so /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libshared_memory.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libreal_time_tools.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so.1.71.0 -lpthread -lpthread -ledit -lcurses -lnsl -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXmu -lm /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libsignal_handler.so 

/usr/bin/c++  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK -DRT_PREEMPT -DUSING_pybind11 -Do80_example_py_EXPORTS -I/home/franka_panda/o80/src/o80_example/include -I/home/franka_panda/o80/src/o80_example/SYSTEM -isystem /usr/include/python3.8 -isystem /home/franka_panda/o80/install/include -isystem /usr/include/eigen3  -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -fPIC   -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/o80_example_py.dir/srcpy/wrappers.cpp.o -c /home/franka_panda/o80/src/o80_example/srcpy/wrappers.cpp

/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC  -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic  -shared  -o o80_example.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so CMakeFiles/o80_example_py.dir/srcpy/wrappers.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/home/franka_panda/o80/build/o80_example:/home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib:::::::::::::::: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so libo80_example.so /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libo80.so /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libsynchronizer.so /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libtime_series.so /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libshared_memory.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libreal_time_tools.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so.1.71.0 -lpthread -lpthread -ledit -lcurses -lnsl -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXmu -lm /home/franka_panda/o80/install/lib/libsignal_handler.so

franka_o80:
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC  -Wl,--no-as-needed /usr/local/lib/libreal_time_tools.so /usr/local/lib/libshared_memory.so /usr/local/lib/libsignal_handler.so /usr/local/lib/libsynchronizer.so /usr/local/lib/libtime_series.so /usr/local/lib/libo80.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,libfranka_o80_cpp.so -o libfranka_o80_cpp.so CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/driver.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/driver_input_output.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/driver_input.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/driver_output.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/kinematics.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/standalone.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/states.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/state.cpp.o   -L/opt/ros/noetic/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/noetic/lib -lfranka -lpinocchio /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.71.0 -lrt -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so.1.71.0 -lpthread 

/usr/bin/c++  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK -DROSCONSOLE_BACKEND_LOG4CXX -DROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"franka_o80\" -DRT_PREEMPT -DUSING_pybind11 -Dfranka_o80_EXPORTS -I/opt/ros/noetic/include -I/opt/ros/noetic/include/libfranka -I/opt/ros/noetic/share/xmlrpcpp/cmake/../../../include/xmlrpcpp -I/usr/include/eigen3 -isystem /usr/include/python3.8  -fPIC   -fvisibility=hidden -Wl,--no-as-needed -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/franka_o80.dir/src/wrappers.cpp.o -c /home/franka_panda/franka_o80/src/wrappers.cpp

/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC  -Wl,--no-as-needed /usr/local/lib/libreal_time_tools.so /usr/local/lib/libshared_memory.so /usr/local/lib/libsignal_handler.so /usr/local/lib/libsynchronizer.so /usr/local/lib/libtime_series.so /usr/local/lib/libo80.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,libfranka_o80_cpp.so -o libfranka_o80_cpp.so CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/driver.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/driver_input_output.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/driver_input.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/driver_output.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/kinematics.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/standalone.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/states.cpp.o CMakeFiles/franka_o80_cpp.dir/src/state.cpp.o   -L/opt/ros/noetic/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/noetic/lib -lfranka -lpinocchio /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.71.0 -lrt -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so.1.71.0 -lpthread
```

I can't see where the dark magic happens.

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# franka_o80_cpp
add_library(franka_o80_cpp SHARED ..........)
target_include_directories(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC ${franka_control_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC ${pinocchio_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_directories(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC ${franka_control_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC franka)
target_link_libraries(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC pinocchio)
target_link_libraries(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC Boost::system Boost::thread)
target_link_libraries(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC rt pthread)
target_compile_options(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC -Wl,--no-as-needed)
target_link_options(franka_o80_cpp PUBLIC -Wl,--no-as-needed /usr/local/lib/libreal_time_tools.so /usr/local/lib/libshared_memory.so /usr/local/lib/libsignal_handler.so /usr/local/lib/libsynchronizer.so /usr/local/lib/libtime_series.so /usr/local/lib/libo80.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib)
# franka_o80
if (pybind11_FOUND)
    add_library(franka_o80 MODULE src/wrappers.cpp)
    target_compile_definitions(franka_o80 PRIVATE USING_pybind11)
    target_link_libraries(franka_o80 PRIVATE pybind11::module)
    target_link_libraries(franka_o80 PRIVATE ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(franka_o80 PRIVATE franka_o80_cpp)
    set_target_properties(franka_o80 PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
endif()
```

Code, rather boring:

```
pybind11::module::import("o80");
m.def("fucntion_using_mode", [](o80::Mode){});
```

Same things happen with all other types, `Mode` is just for simplicity. Ubuntu 20.04, g++ 9.3.0. Please help. `o80` has overengineered ecosystem, it will take weeks to integrate with it. I'll provide all logs I can. Thank you.

UPD: changed lnking options from `-lo80` to `o80.so`, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For pybind11 to treat two classes as the same, not only their name should be equal, but also the file. `o80`'s bindings were compiled with `path_to_sources/install/include` included, but my bindings were compiled with `/usr/local/include` included, so Python did not recognize them.